This FileNotFoundError keeps happening, and im unsure how to fix it
So, i've got this function, readFile(filename) and i've done all the code right (as far as I and ChatGPT can tell) and the .txt file im trying to read is in the same folder, yet it always returns a FileNotFound error. Here is the function:
def readFile(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        return lines
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "File not found"

and how i'm using it:
WordList = readFile("wordList.txt")
print(WordList)

and it always prints 'File not found'
I checked I typed the code and everything correctly, which didn't work, then asked ChatGPT which proposed some solutions which didn't work again. I tried restarting VS code and it still didn't work. I was expecting a list with 1000 items in it (as my .txt document was just a list of words 1000 lines long, 1 line per word) but it just returned 'File not found'.

is the file present in the same PATH as where you are running the script ?

Yes. I checked.

Try printing the result of os.getcwd() to know the working directory. or os.listdir() to ensure the file indeed there.

idk what os.listdir() is sorry

I don't know how to use that function nor os.getcwd

import os then run these functions

This is totally beside the point, but that try-except isn't very helpful. Usually, you as the developer want to get the traceback so you can see exactly where an error occurred and any other details, not that that would help in this case though. There's also a bunch of design principles I could bring up, but you seem like a beginner so I don't want to nitpick, unless you're interested. Suffice to say, if I were you, I'd remove it or at least move it outside the function.

(Moving it outside the function would involve changing return "File not found" to print("File not found").)

The code is looking for the file in the current directory, which is NOT necessarily the same directory as the python script.
